# SQL subs select sometimes returning 2 values causing extra Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a SQL statement like the following.
Right now it's returning values for both ProjectRate and Rate.
I want it to return rate when rate >= 0 and not null.
If that's not true I want to return Project rate when Project Rate is >= 0 and not null.
If they are both null or both <0 I want to return 0.
Right now it's returning Rate and ProjectRate if they both exist instead of picking Rate over ProjectRate

And I have all the tables joined correctly, I just used the generic names to keep it simple

EDIT:
Here's the full query

```
select distinct 
ph.ID_ProjectHours, 
ph.Status,
ph.HoursQuantity,
ph.EntryDate,
ph.EntryYear,
ph.EntryMonth,
ph.EntryWeek,
ph.EntryDescription,
ph.DeliverableCode,
ph.WBSLine,
ph.ItemValue,
ph.ItemDescription,
ph.LastModifiedDate,
ph.LastModifiedUser,
ph.SynergyRequestID,
p.ProjectName,
p.ProjectDescription,
p.ProjectManager,
p.ProjectBudgetTimeMat,
p.ProjectBudgetFixed,
p.ProjectRate,
p.ProjectBudget,
p.ProjectContingency,
p.ContingencyType,
p.ContingencyRemaining,
p.Discount,
p.GoLiveDate,
p.InvoiceInstruction,
e.EmployeeName,
e.FTE,
b.TypeName,
bt.BudgetTypeName,
cc.CostCenterName,
cc.CostCenterDescription,
CFU.CFUName,
d.DepartmentName,
c.CustomerName,
c.CustomerSynergyID,
i.InternalRate,
i.Currency,
i.StartDate as RateStart,
i.EndDate as RateEnd,
(select(coalesce(case when per.Rate > 0 then Rate else null end, case when p.ProjectRate > 0 then p.ProjectRate else null end, 0))) as CalcRate

from dbo.ProjectHours as ph
    inner join dbo.Project as p
        on p.ID_Project = ph.ID_Project
    inner join dbo.Employee as e
        on e.ID_Employee = ph.ID_Employee
    inner join dbo.BillableType as b
        on b.ID_BillableType = ph.ID_BillableType
    inner join dbo.BudgetType as bt
        on p.ID_BudgetType = bt.ID_BudgetType
    inner join dbo.CostCenter as cc
        on cc.ID_CostCenter = p.ID_CostCenter
    inner join dbo.CFU
        on cc.ID_CFU = CFU.ID_CFU
    inner join dbo.Department as d
        on CFU.ID_Department = d.ID_Department
    inner join dbo.Customer as c
        on c.ID_Customer = p.ID_Customer
    left join dbo.Internal as i
        on i.ID_Employee = e.ID_Employee and i.InternalRate <> 0 and 
ph.EntryDate between i.StartDate and i.EndDate 
    left join dbo.ProjectEmployeeRates as per
        on per.ID_Employee = e.ID_Employee
```

Comment: Sample data and results might explain what is happening.

Comment: I think it would help to see a schema for the relevant tables

Comment: waht's the point of `(select * from dbo.ProjectEmployeeRates 
    where per.ID_Project =ph.ID_Project and per.ID_Employee = ph.ID_Employee)`? You don't have any tables aliased as per or ph so where are these coming from?

Comment: @scsimon they are aliases in my code. As as I said in the bottom part of my question I used generic table and column names to keep it simple. My query is quite lengthy. There is a long list of joins in my actual query

Comment: I can understand jake, but not including that part of the code reduces our visibility and thus we will likely miss an easier solution. Any chance you can include it?

Answer (score 1):

Try your case statement like this:

```
    Case 
       when Rate >= 0 then Rate
       when ProjectRate >= 0 then ProjectRate
       else 0
    end
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. Do you think it could be because Rate and Project Rate are in different tables?